# Spring Batch - Using an ItemWriter with List of Lists

Tags: java, spring-batch

Our processor returns a `List<?>` (effectively passing a `List<List<?>>`) to our `ItemWriter`.

Now, we observed that the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is not programmed to handle `item instanceof List`. We also observed to process item instanceof `List`; we need to write a custom `ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider`.

But the sad part is that it returns `SqlParameterSource` which can handle only one `item` and again not capable of handling a `List`.

So, can someone help us understand how to handle list of lists in the `JdbcBatchItemWriter`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typically, the design pattern is:

```
Reader -> reads something, returns ReadItem
Processor -> ingests ReadItem, returns ProcessedItem
Writer -> ingests List<ProcessedItem>
```

If your processor is returning `List<Object>`, then you need your Writer to expect `List<List<Object>>`.

You could do this by wrapping your `JdbcBatchItemWriter` as a delegate in an ItemWriter that looks something like this:

```
public class ListUnpackingItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<List<T>>, ItemStream, InitializingBean {

    private ItemWriter<T> delegate;

    @Override
    public void write(final List<? extends List<T>> lists) throws Exception {
        final List<T> consolidatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final List<T> list : lists) {
            consolidatedList.addAll(list);
        }
        delegate.write(consolidatedList);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(delegate, "You must set a delegate!");
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).open(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).update(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (delegate instanceof ItemStream) {
            ((ItemStream) delegate).close();
        }
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemWriter<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent solution suggested. We were planning to do something more complex by implementing http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/122284-how-to-write-a-list-of-items-with-a-itemwriter; but your solution is generic enough. In latter we would require a lot of job to be done. Testing it was also going to get cumbersome.

Comment: Very good formatting of the code, do you have a template available for this?

Comment: It may be more efficient to built a list and execute a writer once.

Comment: @Dean Clark : I'm getting null pointer exception at delegate.write(consolidatedList);

Comment: @yuva Are you sure you've set a delegate? This is a bare-bones version of the class. In reality, it should also implement `InitializingBean` and have an assertion that a delegate writer has been provided.

Comment: I recommend creating a new question with your current setup.

Comment: I ask how to set Resource File? I am tried this example but I don't khnow how to set the output file

Comment: You'd need to set it in your delegate `ItemWriter`. This writer can work for a file writer, DB writer, MQ writer, etc. So you may want to use a `FlatFileItemWriter` as your delegate, and can set your output resource there.

Comment: Is there any sample code snippet on how to create a delete for `FlatFileItemWriter` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ListUnpackingItemWriter<T> implements FlatFileItemWriter<List<T>>, ItemStream, InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setLineAggregator(item -> String.join("\n", item.stream().map(T::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }

}
```

Just added a custom line aggregator to the above solution, this helps in writing the content to a file by using `FlatFileItemWriter<List<T>>`. You can replace `T` with actual class name to avoid compilation error while calling `toString()` method.

Comment: There's no `setLineAggregator` method in `ItemWriter`. This should probably be called on the underlying delegate writer.

Comment: Correct, the method `setLineAggregator()` not present in `ItemWriter` and it's present in `FlatFileItemWriter`.