# Writing List of Items using JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: list, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, compositeitemwriter

Currently i am using JpaItemWriter to write the list of objects as below which is working fine.
Now i want to change the JpaItemWriter to JdbcBatchItemWriter due to performance issue.

```
    public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<MyDomainObject>> {

    @Override  
    public void write(List<? extends Lists<MyDomainObject>> items) {
    JpaItemWriter<MyDomainObject> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();    
    for(List<MyDomainObject> o : items)
        {
          writer.write(o);
        }
      }
    }
```

Suggest a sample snippets which uses the JdbcBatchItemWriter to write the List of objects will helps. Tried using the ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider it did't help ending up in `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter`  exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You example is not correct. You are creating a `JpaItemWriter` in the `write` method, so a new instance is created on each call to `write`. This is probably the cause of your performance issue.

More importantly, lifecycle methods of the delegate writer (open/update/close) will not be honored (it is not the case for `JpaItemWriter` which does not implement `ItemStream` but this would be a problem if the delegate is an item stream). Your `MyItemWriter` implementation should be something like:

```
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<MyDomainObject>> {

   private JpaItemWriter jpaItemWriter;

   public MyItemWriter(JpaItemWriter jpaItemWriter) {
      this. jpaItemWriter = jpaItemWriter;
   }

   @Override  
   public void write(List<? extends Lists<MyDomainObject>> items) {  
     for(List<MyDomainObject> o : items) {
       this. jpaItemWriter.write(o);
     }
   }
}
```

Now if you want to use the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to write a list of lists, see [Spring Batch - Using an ItemWriter with List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866312/using-an-itemwriter-with-list-of-lists).

Edit: Added a sample code of how to set the delegate as requested in comments:

```
@Bean
public ListUnpackingItemWriter<T> itemWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<T> jdbcBatchItemWriter = null; // configure your jdbcBatchItemWriter
    ListUnpackingItemWriter<T> listUnpackingItemWriter = new ListUnpackingItemWriter<>();
    listUnpackingItemWriter.setDelegate(jdbcBatchItemWriter);
    return listUnpackingItemWriter;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hassine, thanks for your detailed information. It really helps me in understanding the code in detail.
Now i am trying to follow the solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866312/using-an-itemwriter-with-list-of-lists but ending up in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must set a delegate!` error. Also there is no solution for this exception in that post. Can you please help in this?

Comment: You need to call the setter `setDelegate` and set the delegate item writer you want to use.

Comment: I understand that, but i am bit unclear about how to set the Delegate for my specific writer. Do we have any sample snippet to look over?