# Spring batch FlatFileItemWriter consume a list<object>

Tags: spring-batch

I need to write a Step with :

- reader JpaPagingItemReader
- processor that return a List
- writer that writer foreach student that returned from processor a line in csv file.

How it is possible? how write a costum "FlatFileItemWriter" that consume a list and for each object write a line into FileResource?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - Using an ItemWriter with List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866312/spring-batch-using-an-itemwriter-with-list-of-lists)

Comment: i have created the ListUnpackingItemWriter class like a example, but how use it in my Bean "FlatFileItemWriter" ? Explain me an example how to use che ListUnpackingItemWriter class?   thanks

Comment: Use the same example with your `FlatFileItemWriter` as delegate instead of the  `JdbcBatchItemWriter`.

Comment: @DavideBoldrin were u able to find a solution?