# Unloading from tables with data transformation using Spring Batch

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch, json-flattener

I want to do a dump from tables using Spring Batch. I need to dump data from the *customer* input table to the *customer_data* output table. The *customer* table has a *data* column of type String (jsonb).
I need to get json from the *data* column and convert it to flatten map format, then dump this data into the *field* (key) and *value* (value) columns in the *customer_data* table.

Is there a nice solution how to do this with Spring Batch? I'm not sure if this needs to be implemented in the InputRowMapper because there are many records to be saved to a new *customer_data* table.

Input (*customer*):

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class CustomerDataInput {

    private Long id;
    private String data;
}
```

Where *data*:

```
{
   "template":"test",
   "description":"example"
}
```

Output (*customer_data*):

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class CustomerDataOutput {

    private Long jobId;
    private Long id;
    private Long dataId;
    private String field;
    private Object value;
}
```

I expect this:

| job_id | id | data_id | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | template | test |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | description | example |

Comment: Does this mean that an input item is transformed to multiple output items? Please share an example with a couple input/output records to explain your requirement. Also, please share your code with your specific issue to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: [Mahmoud Ben Hassine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019386/mahmoud-ben-hassine) Yes that's right. I have added an example of input / output data.

Comment: [Mahmoud Ben Hassine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019386/mahmoud-ben-hassine) As I understand it, I need to use an ItemWriter in the CustomerDataProcessor class that will work with List<CustomerDataOutput>. But I can't seem to find a working implementation to write a list of entities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - Using an ItemWriter with List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866312/spring-batch-using-an-itemwriter-with-list-of-lists)

Comment: [Mahmoud Ben Hassine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019386/mahmoud-ben-hassine) thanks for the answer, I have researched the given example, but I get NullPointerException at delegate.write(consolidatedList) even though I am doing listUnpackingItemWriter.setDelegate(itemWriter) in my CustomerDataStepConfiguration class